# Start Loading with Enter Block

Tags: anylogic

I would like to start loading my truck when the truck arrives at the dock. How could I activate the enter block startloading? When it comes to the block pickupOrders, the truck doesn't load my pallets because I don't know how to activate the block enter "startloading". The source block is part of the agent "truck", the enter block is part of the agent "pallet".

[process_logic_simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsmQt.png)
[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OKal.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Help article](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FPickup.html&resultof=%22%70%69%63%6B%75%70%22%20), you need to fill the queue for the Pickup block yourself.

Your Enter block cannot create agents that fill up your queue (see the help on what an Enter block does). Replace it with a Source block to actually create agents directly.

If, however, your agents for the queue already exist, you can push them into your Enter block using an Exit block from where they live. In the Exit block "on Exit" code, write `myEnterBlock.take(agent)` to push them in.

Also, many example models showing you Enter/Exit setup in more detail.

Comment: When I take the source block instead of enter  it says pallet rack does not contain the agent.

Comment: do you know an example model except distribution center where the trucks load material? I have a big problem to understand how to load my trucks/ how to get the connection between truck and dock.

Comment: Not sure, there are lots of example models. "I have a big problem to..." is, again, not helpful here :) Also, "when I take the source block it says..." is not helpful. Best turn it into a new question, state what you have already tried yourself (!!), what the problem is, ... Learn to use SOF to your advantage and you have a lot of power at your hand :)

Comment: I solved this problem too. Thank you for your help.